# Split into multiple files grouped by column value using AWK

Tags: awk

My data frame is something similar to this in structure:

```
    A   C
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   a   4
5   b   5
6   b   6
7   b   7
8   b   8
9   c   9
```

it has 16 million rows, I'm facing memory issues while processing in Python. I tried to split this file using `split` command, but I don't want to spread values in `A` column into different files. 
 
I don't want something like this:

File one:

```
 A   C
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   a   4
5   b   5
6   b   6
```

File two:

```
7   b   7
8   b   8
9   c   9
```

Something like this would work:

File one:

```
 A   C
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   a   4
5   b   5
6   b   6
7   b   7
8   b   8
```

File two:

```
9   c   9
```

Let me know, if I'm not clear.  I wrote a script to do this job in python-pandas, but it's taking long time. Any quick solution using awk?

EDIT:
My python script to split this file, this file is taking too long.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os

tp = pd.read_table(sys.argv[1], iterator=True, chunksize=int(sys.argv[2]))
gff3File = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
i = 0
colNames = ['query_id', 'subject_id', 'percent_idendity', 'align_len', 'mismatch', 'gap_opens', 'q_start', 'q_end', 's_start', 's_end', 'evalue', 'bit_score']
result = pd.DataFrame(columns= colNames)
os.mkdir('splitted')
os.chdir('splitted')
print(len(gff3File))

while True:
    first_gene = gff3File.loc[gff3File["query_id"] == gff3File.query_id.iloc[0]]
    gff3File = gff3File[gff3File["query_id"] != gff3File.query_id.iloc[0]]
    result = result.append(first_gene)
    #print(len(first_gene))
    if len(result) >= int(sys.argv[2]) or len(gff3File) == 0:
        result.to_csv(''.join(['split', "_", str(i), '.csv']), sep = ',')
        print("wrote to:",''.join(['split', "_", str(i), '.csv']))
        result = pd.DataFrame(columns= colNames)
        i+=1
    if len(gff3File) == 0: break
```

Head of my data:

```
query_id    subject_id  percent_idendity    align_len   mismatch    gap_opens   q_start q_end   s_start s_end   evalue  bit_score
LOC_Os01g01010.1    Chr1    100.00  811 0   0   370 1180    7134    7944    0.0 1498
LOC_Os01g01010.1    Chr1    100.00  410 0   0   1592    2001    9208    9617    0.0  758
LOC_Os01g01010.1    Chr1    100.00  202 0   0   1392    1593    8407    8608    2e-101   374
LOC_Os01g01010.1    Chr1    100.00  169 0   0   1   169 3449    3617    4e-83    313
LOC_Os01g01010.1    Chr1    82.25   338 30  19  1669    1996    43230640    43230323    1e-68    265
```

Here, I don't want to spread `query_id` to different files while splitting.

Comment: How many files do you want to split them into?

Comment: It depends on number of lines I have on that particular file. In this case five.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't understand this, but shouldn't you want a single file for your given example because the `query_id` is the same for all 5 rows?

Comment: I have 16 million lines in that file, I just printed head of five lines. I want to split 16 million lines into 5 files.

Comment: @Merlin That's 1GB. Read the 'KB' at the end :P

Comment: What about reading your file in chunks using `read_csv(filename, chunksize=10**6)` and saving/adding  chunks into HDF5 file? Later on you can read your HDF5 conditionally, using `where('condition')` function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Since the OP wanted to group several keys into a single file, I wrote a less simple AWK script to do the processing!

```
BEGIN {
    query_count = 0
    file_index = 0
}
{
    if ($2 in arr)
        print >> arr[$2]".split"
    else {
        arr[$2] = file_index
        print > arr[$2]".split"
    }   
    if ( query_count % 5000 == 0 )
        file_index++
    query_count++
}
END {
    for ( key in arr )
        print key ": " arr[key]
}
```

**Explanation**:

For every *5000* records, it will group the `keys` into a file. For any record in the entire database, the records with those *5000* `keys` will be fixed into file `0.split`. After which it keeps increment to `1.split` and so on.

Please note, this does not mean that *5000* records go into 1 file. A little bit of careful thought should be suffice to reach to a more optimized number for your dataset, *5000* should work fine for a general non-specific set.

With a value of 5 instead of *5000* for the OP's example, the above script produces the following output:

```
  cat 0.split                                                             
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   a   4
5   b   5
6   b   6
7   b   7
8   b   8
  cat 1.split                                                             
9   c   9
```

---

***Initial naive solution***:

This simple awk script will work beautifully.

```
awk '{print >> $1".split"}' subset.data
```

What this does is uses your `query_id.split` as a filename, effectively grouping the entire data using the `query_id`.

Your example when run on the above awk script produces the following files:

```
  awk '{print >> $2".split"}' temp.data                                   
  cat a.split                                                             
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   a   4
  cat b.split                                                             
5   b   5
6   b   6
7   b   7
8   b   8
  cat c.split                                                             
9   c   9
```

Comment: This is not I want. I have 16 million lines in that file (possibly few thousand different values in `A` column), while splitting 16 million lines into 5 files, I don't want to spread a value in `query_id` (like few `a` in one file and few `a` in another file) into different files.

Comment: @ramesh after splitting the files in the way I described above, you can easily concatenate them into 5 files using `cat`. Since each file has unique keys, conctenated files will never share keys with other files. I know this is redundant and I could hack together a more complex AWK script to optimize this process, but it's definitely worth a try if you can make do with this quick hack.

Comment: Yes, that's a very good alternative! But imagine if I have some 80K values in `query_id`. My python script does this same thing, it's taking too long, that's my problem. I know `awk` is too good for this purpose but I'm very poor in awk.

Comment: @ramesh Let me try and script something for you then. No promises though :)

Comment: @ramesh, are you going to read/parse your splitted CSV files to pandas data frames? If you're using pandas just for splitting your CSV file, then i think AWK - is a good choice

Comment: @ramesh I've updated the answer. It should suit your needs perfectly ;) Cheers!

Comment: @ramesh, part of the problem you had with your python script --was there was a infinite  loop.

Comment: @MiteshNinja:Thanks!

Comment: @ramesh If it worked, please accept it as an answer for future travelers :)

Comment: @MiteshNinja: your solution is very beautiful :) You saved my day :) :)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

you want to split the dataframe into different files grouped by column `'A'`.

Please test on a small subset of your data.

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda df: df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(df.loc[:, 'A'].iloc[0])))
```