# How to output the results of awk instructions to a different directory than the one being currently worked in

Tags: awk

**Background:** I have 48 files I am attempting to split by the value in a certain column using awk. An example of my data is:

```
chr pos ref alt reffrq  info    rs  pval    effalt  gene
chr1    13417   C   CGAGA   0.0915493   1   rs777038595 0.978587    0.0051328   DDX11L1
chr1    17559   G   C   0.00662252  1   rs866150608 0.138321    0.985859    DDX11L1
chr1    54421   A   G   0.0448276   1   rs146477069 0.534267    0.177514    BLAH
chr1    54490   G   A   0.191489    1   rs141149254 0.830873    0.0307553   BLAH
```

In this file the `gene` column is made up of thousands of different names and I want to split these huge files into a file for each different gene name (so I end up here with `DDX11L1.txt` and `BLAH.txt`).

As per the [code found here in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910560/split-into-multiple-files-grouped-by-column-value-using-awk) I have a solution which would work on each file one by one:

```
awk '{print >> $10".txt"}' tissue1.txt
```

**Question:** What I want to do now, however, is iterate this over each of the 48 files automatically and have each of the split files separated into a new directory for each of the larger files.

This is what I have come up with so far (where `tissue` is defined earlier from a table and is also the prefix for each of the large files):

```
mkdir /inputs/"$tissue"
workingDir=/inputs/"$tissue"

awk -v tissue="$tissue" -v workingDir="$workingDir" '{print >> "$workingDir"/$10".txt"}' "$tissue"_input.txt
```

The problem being here that this outputs the files into the same directory I am currently in and then the names of the files are `$workingDirGENENAME.txt` which obviously isn't what I want. So essentially I am just not understanding where I need to be putting the variables for the output directory.

Comment: Worth noting that ```awk -v tissue="$tissue" -v workingDir="$workingDir" '{print >> "/inputs/workingdirectory/"$10".txt"}' "$tissue"_input.txt``` seems to work. So the issue here is that I can't use a variable instead of a directory...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was just a misunderstanding of the syntax Awk uses.

The following seems to work:

```
awk -v tissue="$tissue" -v workingDir="$workingDir" '{print >> workingDir "/" $10".txt"}' "$tissue"_input.txt
```